Trying to import a multi signature wallet in Bitcoin core
10 years ago I sent 0.01 BTC to a multi-signature address which requires two passwords
I am now trying to import this wallet in Bitcoin Core but I am not able to.
The information I have is:

The BTC address where the BTC is stored
The public key
The passphrase I used as a first password
The second password which was hidden under a hologram on a physical Bitcoin coin

Can anyone guide me as to how to do it?
I am now downloading the whole Bitcoin Core along with the blockchain.
Thank you!
